# Table text font

Tags: tables

I have the script shown below. The problem is that the table font size is larger than the document font size that I specified in the first line. How to make the table font use the same font size as the rest of the document.

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx} %for images

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}

\begin{document}
\title{Test Document}

% make the title area
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction.

\begin{table}[bt!] 
\caption{A map}
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} {
\begin{tabular} {@{} lc*{3}l @{}}
\hline
Message Name &
Abbreviation &
Used In\\
\hline
Hello & H & Fig.  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}%end resize box
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple, don't use `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} {...}` If the table should span the whole width of the column, have a look at the `tabularx` package.

Comment: Related: [Setting table-width exactly to linewidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240154/setting-table-width-exactly-to-linewidth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tabularx`. You never should use `\resizebox` for code containing text. Also use the rules from `booktabs` to give your rules some padding:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx} %for images

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Test Document}

% make the title area
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is an introduction.

\begin{table}[!hbt]
\caption{A map}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth} {@{} l*{3}{X} @{}}
\toprule
Message Name &
Abbreviation &
Used In\\
\midrule
Hello & H & Fig. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]