# Two column table over textwidth is messing up right column (tabular*)

Tags: tables

**Problem solved:** Package *ltablex* was loaded before tabularx and thus it didn't work. Using tabularx is working now!

So I would like to set up a table over the whole textwidth with two columns.
It's almost working, except the right column is shifted to the right and I don't know how to fix this.

I tried to adapt the solution from this question: [Setting table-width exactly to linewidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240154/setting-table-width-exactly-to-linewidth) and this is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{scrbook}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|l|}
    \hline
    left column & right column \\
    \hline
    left column & right column
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

but this is the result:

[image: Latex table with two columns over linewidth with wrong column space]

Why is the right column so much shifted to the right? And the left column has zero space to the right. How can I fix this so that the left column uses as much space as needed and the right column fills the linewidth?

My desired output should look like this:

[image]

With the left column only using as much space as needed and the right column filling up the rest of the horizontal space.

I already tried it with tabularx but this isn't working either:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    left column & right column \\
    \hline
    left column & right column \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Not working two column table example with tabularx]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Use `\noindent` before the table. ->`\noindent
\begin{tabular*}`. WIth \usepackage{showframe} you could visualize margins.

Comment: Why not use the `tabularx` package and its flexible width `X` column?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see the indent but this isn't my main problem. The right column should be left aligned next to the left column without that huge horizontal space in between.

Comment: Already tried tabularx but with tabularx it isn't working at all. Will update the question with my tabularx example

Comment: @Robert: could you please turn your code fragment into a compilable MWE? With the information you posted, I am not able to recreate the issue you have with `tabularx`.

Comment: in your table you require, that between columns is maximal available space for `\tabcolsep`. consequently it is extended to text in second column. what you like actually achieve? equal width of cells?

Comment: Ok: Added some code for a MWE and a picture with a desired output (quickly made with a spreadsheet).

Comment: Wouldn't you be loading `\tablex` without specifying `\keepXColumns`?

Comment: @Robert - What do you get if you compile the code in my answer (copy-paste as is)?

Comment: last image in your question is not produced by code which you claim to use for it. see Bernard answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this column specification:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}
    \hline
    left column & right column \\
    \hline
    left column & right column \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Problem solved... I had the package ltablex loaded before tabularx and thus it didn't work.  It now works and your solution is the best looking!

Answer (score 0):

It does work with `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X| >{\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
    left column & right column \\
    \hline
    left column & right column \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]